# Behat mink test multiple pages

Tags: behat, mink

I'm new to behat.
what I want to do is test a bunch of pages if they exist or not.

this is my example:

```
Scenario: Page "contact"
Given I am on "/contact"
Then I should see "contact"
```

in the footer you see a link called contact
so if there is some php error the it quits and I don't see the footer so behat fails.

but can I select multiple names like this:

```
Given I am on [/, /contact, /about-me] etc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have many options but I'm just giving you two for now so for more, you can do your own research:

This is what many people would do:

**Feature file:**

```
Scenario: Checking pages and their content
Given I am on "/"
Then I should see "welcome home"
When I am on "/contact"
Then I should see "welcome to contact page"
When I am on "/about-me"
Then I should see "welcome to about me page"
When I am on "/whatever"
Then I should see "welcome to whatever page"
......
......
```

This is another option which verifies physical existence of the files:

**Feature file:**

```
Scenario: Checking pages and but not their content
Given I am on "/"
Then I should see "welcome home"
And the files below must exist in my project folder:
      | file |
      | /path/to/my/project/files/contact.tml  |
      | /path/to/my/project/files/about-me.tml  |
      | /path/to/my/project/files/whatever.tml  |
```

**In your FeatureContext file:**

```
class FeatureContext extends MinkContext
{
    /**
     * @When /^the files below must exist in my project folder:$/
     */
    public function theFilesBelowMustExistInMyProjectFoder(TableNode $table)
    {
        foreach ($table->getHash() as $file) {
            if (file_exists($file) !== true) {
                throw new Exception(sprintf('File "%s" not found', $file));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that makes perfect sense now I have an idea where to start